# Why is Having More Threads than Cores Faster?

Tags: multithreading, performance, pthreads

I've implemented a version of PageRank in a multithreaded version. I'm running it on a 4-core Q6600. When I run it set to create 4 threads, I get:

```
real    6.968s
user   26.020s
sys     0.050s
```

When I run with 128 threads I get:

```
real    0.545s
user    1.330s
sys     0.040s
```

This makes no sense to me. The basic algorithm is a sum-reduce:

1. All threads sum a subset of the input;
2. Synchronize;
3. Each thread then accumulates part of the results from the other threads;
4. The main thread sums an intermediate value from all the threads and then determines whether to continue.

Profiling hasn't helped. I'm not sure what data would be helpful to understand my code - please just ask.

It really has me puzzled.

Comment: What's the input in this case? Something IO-bound? Do you have measurements for each of the individual steps?

Comment: Is it possible that with many more threads, each thread is getting a small enough chunk to complete in one time slice? Some scheduling systems give a little extra time in the first slice for a thread. If it doesn't complete in time, it gets scheduled and takes part in the normal slices. If the work is being broken down to really simple levels, you could be "gaming the system" by getting many more slices for your application and robbing other processes. You could try running in higher priority too and see if you get similar results.

Comment: The input is all read in at the start, so not IO bound. I rewrote a substantial part of the multi-threading code and removed an instance of false sharing. The false-sharing fix increased the speed slightly.

Comment: I did however optimize the memory usage 4GB -> 600MB which made the difference between 4 and 128 threads negligible. The only explanation I can think of is that I was constrained by memory bandwidth and that each core was accessing a massive range fairly randomly (hence no spatial locality for caching), while with more threads, each thread has a decent amount of spatial locality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Deliberately creating more threads than processors is a standard technique used to make use of "spare cycles" where a thread is blocked waiting for something, whether that's I/O, a mutex, or something else by providing some other useful work for the processor to do.

If your threads are doing I/O then this is a strong contender for the speed-up: as each thread blocks waiting for the I/O, the processor can run the other threads until they too block for I/O, hopefully by which time the data for the first thread is ready, and so forth.

Another possible cause of the speed up is that your threads are experiencing **false sharing**. If you have two threads writing data to different values on the same cache line (e.g. adjacent elements of an array) then this will block the CPU whilst the cache line is transferred back and forth. By adding more threads you decrease the likelihood that they are operating on adjacent elements, and thus reduce the chance of false sharing. You can easily test this by adding extra padding to your data elements so they are each at least 64 bytes in size (the typical cache line size). If your 4-thread code speeds up, this was the problem.

Comment: The guess about false sharing is a very good one. But considering the huge difference in run time, I rather suspect a race condition bug in the work partitioning logic, so that the version with many threads "forgets" some jobs and just doesn't do as much as the other one.

Answer (score 7):

You probably have spare CPU cycles while the thread blocks for some resources like memory. These CPU cycles can be used by other threads.  The data I'd look at is... Does the 4 thread version show 100% utilization of each core? If not the you've found your spare CPU cycles.