# MultiThreading - 5 or 100 threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a **dual core** processor, now let's say that I want to make a spam bot program, which will spam messages such as "Hey, how are you?".

My question is, what number of threads would be able to pop up these messages the fastest, running 5 threads or 100 threads botting the messages? (Of course, these numbers aren't special, just for the example). All of the threads will run in thread-safe.

**EDIT:** As for the down votes before, I'm not really writing a spambot program, I just mentioned it as an example for my question, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @idish: I realize you're not doing a spam bot, but I downvoted because it's not clear what you're asking.  What do threads have to do with popping up messages?  If you simply want to pop them up as fast as possible, and want to know what number of threads could do that the fastest before they choke each other that's one thing, but as it is, the question's wording is very unclear.

Comment: @MooingDuck You're right, It's pretty hard for me to describe my question properly, but this is the right description actually: "pop them up as fast as possible, and want to know what number of threads could do that the fastest before they choke each other "

Comment: @idish: my concern is that the code as described is limited by OS calls, and will probably top out at one thread.  _Maybe_ one per core.  And it seems unlikely that your real code will be as OS-call dominated as the question describes, making all potential answers useless.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I don't think my answer is useless :-)

Comment: @MooingDuck His answer isn't useless at all, he helped me undestand things I didn't know.

Comment: @EricJ. Good point, your answer is actually generic enough about multithreading that it's not useless.  Good job!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ideal number of threads depends on your hardware (in this case a dual core processor), and on what those threads are doing.  If they are CPU intensive, more than 1 thread per core will probably slow things down.

If the threads do some IO, you will see an overall increase in performance by adding threads.  The point of diminishing returns depends entirely on the nature of the non-CPU tasks and on the specific hardware.

To find that point, you will have to test various thread totals.

You can design your system to self-tune the number of threads in use.  I once designed a system that ran best (most total throughput) when the total CPU load was about 70%.  To optimize for that value, I added threads (with a delay between threads) until the CPU was at 70%, +/- 5%.  If it went above 80%, I signaled one or more threads to finish their current work and terminate.  If it went below 60%, I gradually added threads.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, and supporting my question up there ^^. I'm not sure if you're gaining any points because the question is already closed but I will accept your answer anyways, thank you very much.

Comment: Well, the question is almost reopened (4 of 5 required votes as of now).  Points are awarded for closed questions (but not for deleted ones).  Anyhow, it's about helping people.  Points are secondary.

Comment: My thoughts in the past were to start with a thread, and add about one thread per second until the throughput decreases, and then remove one thread.  Then once in a while, I randomly add or remove a thread, and if throughput decreases, undo that.  Similar concept though.

Comment: You're truly right about it, thanks again, I liked the way you designed your program, I think I'm going to implement that design in my programs too, can you tell me please what was the target of your system?(Was it related to IO?)

Comment: @MooingDuck: That might be better for the general case (though 1 second rampup may not be enough).  In our case, a high-volume billing platform, we carefully measured a number of performance counters and determined that CPU strongly correlated with total throughput, and that peak throughput was at 70% CPU.  Of course, those optima probably drifted a bit over time as the code evolved.

Comment: @idish: It was a billing platform.  The unit of work was to pull a batch of a few 1000 records from a flat Oracle table and perform fairly CPU-intensive work on that batch (apply a number of business rules to identify billable events).  There was IO at the start (pull records) and end (write billable events) of each unit of work.

Comment: @EricJ. Sounds really great work. I may be abit OT for my following question but an answer for it will be really helpful for me. So here it is: I'm a candidate for a very expensive computing project related to programming , could you tell me please what is a unique subject related to C# so the interviewers would be glad to hear that I know? Like I started learning OOD, I'm sorry for questioning this question but it seems that you're an expert and I don't really want to miss that chance asking you. Thank you again.

Comment: +1. Side note: in non-CPU bound cases switching to use proper asynchronous calls will give better results will likely give better results that playing with multiple threads. If you are at the point where resource usage is high enough (like in Eric J's case) custom thread pool may be good option, before that consider using standard thread pool.

Comment: @idish: That really depends on the nature of the software project.  If you like (since it is OT) email me more about the job you are interviewing for (email is in my SO profile).

Answer (score 0):

Deliberately creating more threads than processors is a standard technique used to make use of "spare cycles" where a thread is blocked waiting for something, whether that's I/O, a mutex, or something else by providing some other useful work for the processor to do.

If your threads are doing I/O then this is a strong contender for the speed-up: as each thread blocks waiting for the I/O, the processor can run the other threads until they too block for I/O, hopefully by which time the data for the first thread is ready, and so forth.

Source: [Anthony Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987376/why-is-having-more-threads-than-cores-faster)

Comment: Yes, but if those threads additional are _also_ doing _only_ IO, you won't get any speedup.  You will probably just slow the program down.

Comment: ..depends on the I/O.  With high-latency network connections, a lot of threads will surely provide a large speedup.  Until the number of threads gets rudiculously large, it's actually quite difficult to actually slow down a typical program.