# Java Heap Multithreading Optimization

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, heap-memory

I am writing a Java program that runs many simulations simultaneously in different threads and averages the results together. I want to run a lot of simulations, more than can be running simultaneously, so I want to run as many as I can simultaneously without running out of memory and “queue” the rest.

Is there an easy way to determine the maximum heap memory a thread uses?

Is there an easy way to check how much heap memory is being used at run time so I can only start new threads when memory opens up?

PS: I’m new to optimizing multithreaded applications.

Comment: Have you considered using a Thread Pool?

Answer (score 1):

Profile your threads to determine how much heap is occupied. I know of no way to do this programmatically.

Don't use more threads than you have cores. Creating new threads is a *relatively* expensive operation, and creating too many threads can actually cause your application to run more slowly. If you're processing huge data, or need very low latency, you'll really want to avoid creating many threads.

I suggest looking into [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). Create a fixed thread pool equal to the number of cores on your simulation machine.

Edit:

Since Java 1.4 we've had this available:

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Try this, create a fixed thread pool with `cores` threads. This would allow your application to scale between machines with a difference in cores.

Note this is the number of logical cores, so with Intel's hyperthreading feature it would count 2 "cores" for every processor. Still, a good measurement.

Comment: If the application is IO-bound you may want to use more threads than you have cores. Also, creating new threads is not *that* expensive.

Comment: You're right, threads are a heavy object though. Avoiding unnecessary creation of threads is important. Creating more threads for IO is only necessary to help the app *appear* more responsive. He's only doing simulation here, appearing more responsive is not important.

Comment: More threads may help you with bandwidth, not only latency. This is important when loading, logging, or dumping data for a simulation. But without knowing what the OP's simulation does this is academical.

Comment: How are more threads than # cores going to improve bandwidth? You will be writing/reading data more slowly, so all buffers will fill more slowly than before. Extra small PDU's might get through, but that's not bandwidth as its the same amount of data. And that's the only advantage I see.

Comment: You can have several disks, each with a controller and buffers of its own.

Comment: Right- but they'll still be using the same number processors. Can't supply data faster just because you have more buffers or more controllers. Your output rate went up, but you're still limited by your supply rate.

Comment: Right, that's why I said "if the application is IO-bound." If the "supply rate" is the bottleneck the app is not IO-bound.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I am writing and testing this program on my Laptop (with a I7 processor) but I also have access to a huge 40 core 500GB ram computer it will ultimately run on. It would be nice if the code could go between the two machines without me having to change it a lot, even though their specs are worlds apart.

Comment: You can! There's a property to get the number of processors on a machine. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Here's a use case for running more threads than cores: You have a single Server with N cores pushing a huge data buffer to M Clients via TCP. Let 1000 >= M > N. The server has a Gigabit card, but downstream, each client has a link speed back to the server of 1 Mbit per second.  If we assume a large number of clients, and if the server only runs N threads at a time to push that file to the clients, it will take MUCH longer to fully distribute the file than if the Server had run M threads, simply because it doesn't have enough concurrent outbound connections to saturate that Gigabit card.

Comment: Bottom line - it totally depends on what your app is trying to do.  If you're CPU-bound, then William is correct.  However, if your sim has a situation like the one I've described, then running more threads than number of cores may help.  Just do whatever makes the most sense :)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987376/why-is-having-more-threads-than-cores-faster) Thanks @BenLawry I learned a little something here too.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the program with a single thread while monitoring it in [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), and then with two threads, then with three. The difference in memory usage and garbage collection frequency can give you an idea of how much heap memory a single thread uses and how much of the memory is taken by objects shared between different threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an "easy" task to do, but there are some ways to do it.  The jvm exposes the current memory usage through the management apis.  You can use the MemoryMXBean and the MemoryPoolMXBean to get access to the current jvm memory status.